# Verify stokes theorem example

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, solution-verification, differential-forms

Let $c:I^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ be the singular $2$-cube given by $$c(s,t)=(\frac{1}{2}s^2,st,\frac{1}{2}t^2)$$ Let $$\omega=xy^2dz$$

**Questions**:

i) Compute $c^*\omega$

ii) Compute $c^*d\omega$

iii) Compute $\int_cd\omega$

iv) Without using Stokes theorem, compute $\int_{\partial c}\omega$ (Hence verifying Stokes theorem)

**Answers**:

(Parts (i)-(iii) checked and are correct)

i) I have gotten: $c^*\omega=\frac{1}{2}s^4t^2dt$

ii) $c^*d\omega=d(\frac{1}{2}s^4t^2dt)=2s^3t^2ds\wedge dt$

iii) $\int_cd\omega=2\int_0^1(\int_0^1s^3t^2ds)dt=2\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{6}$

iv) I am using the formula $\int_{\partial c}\omega=\sum_{j=1}^2\sum_{\alpha=0,1}(-1)^{j+\alpha}\int_0^1c^*_{(j,\alpha)}\omega$

I have computed that $c_{(1,0)}(t)=(0,0,\frac{1}{2}t^2),c_{(1,1)}(t)=(\frac{1}{2},t,\frac{1}{2}t^2),c_{(2,0)}(t)=(\frac{1}{2}t^2,0,0),c_{(2,1)}(t)=(\frac{1}{2}t^2,t,\frac{1}{2})$

So $c_{(1,0)}^*\omega=0,c_{(2,0)}^*\omega=0,c_{(2,1)}^*\omega=0$

**Point of contention**:

**My calculation**:

$c_{(1,1)}^*\omega$ is the only non-zero part for $\partial c$

And $c_{(1,1)}^*\omega=\omega(\frac{1}{2},t,\frac{1}{2}t^2)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot t^2\cdot d(\frac{1}{2}t^2)$ from the definition of $\omega=xy^2dz$

This gives $\omega(\frac{1}{2},t,\frac{1}{2}t^2)=\frac{1}{2}t^2\cdot tdt=\frac{1}{2}t^2\cdot tdt$

So I have gotten $c_{(1,1)}^*\omega=\frac{1}{2}t^3dt$

this is wrong since,

**Answer given**: $c_{(1,1)}^*\omega=\frac{1}{2}t^2dt$

and the next step is $$\int_{\partial c}\omega=\int_0^1\frac{1}{2}t^2dt=\frac{1}{6}$$

Which must be correct since this verifies Stokes theorem from part (iii)

And my answer must be wrong since it gives $\int_{\partial c}\omega=\frac{1}{8}$

The answer also has $c_{(1,1)}(t)=(\frac{1}{2},t,\frac{1}{2}t^2)$, but computes $c_{(1,1)}^*\omega$ as $\frac{1}{2}t^2dt$, whereas I get $\frac{1}{2}t^3dt$

Where am I going wrong with this calculation, it is probably a simple mistake, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any chance you might be taking the same class [as this guy](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1097684/compute-int-cd-omega-and-int-partial-c-omega)?

Comment: Yea I know that guy

Comment: Can you help with this last part of the question?